# Working with multiple objects in file

Tags: powershell

I have this script:

```
$inputfile = 'test'
$m1 = Select-String string1 $inputfile
$m2 = Select-String string2 $inputfile `
    | ? { $_.LineNumber -gt $m1.LineNumber } `
    | select -First 1

$m1.Line+$m2.Line >> results.txt
```

It works perfectly, but when there is more then one of `string1` in the file the script dosen't work.
What would you propose to make it compatible with files including more then one of `string1`?

example.file:

```
line string line line text
string text line line string
string2 text line line text
line line text string1 text
line text string2 text text
not text string2 text text
line string1 text text text
string2 text text text text
...
```

The result right now is:    `string2 text line line text`

The desired result is the first line including `string2` after `string1`:

```
line text string2 text text
string2 text text text text
```

Comment: That depends upon what you want your output to be. It's unclear what kind of results you're expecting when you get multiple matches. I'm sure changes can be made to accommodate `$m1` being a collection of results instead of a single result, but without a definition of the final desired output, no good guidance can be given.

Comment: The desired output is the line including `string1` and the first line including `string2`after `string1` in one line.

Comment: i have edited desired result.

Comment: I can see the problem, it's just not clear what you want to accomplish. **$m1** is an *array* of MatchInfo objects, not a single MatchInfo object. When you invoke the methods **.LineNumber** and **.Line** on it, the result is $null. **$m2** is a single MatchInfo object (due to the `| Select -First 1`). So, at the end, when you add **$m1.Line**, which is null, to **$m2.Line**, you get the value of **$m2.Line**, which is `string2 text line line text`. That's the *problem*. For the *solution*, I'd need a better description of what the goal is. On what basis should you get that "desired result"?

Comment: The goal is only to get the first line including `string1` after `string2`.

Comment: edited more precise desired result

Comment: Okay, that's clearer. But it looks like someone else already figured out what you were trying to do. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you specifically looking for a solution using `Select-String`? If not, maybe this can work for you?

```
$lookingFor = "string1";
$string1Line = "";
gc $inputfile | foreach {
  if($_ -match $lookingFor) {
    if($lookingFor -eq "string1") {
      $string1Line = $_;
      $lookingFor = "string2";
    } else { #assuming "string2"
      $string1Line + $_ #return concat of string1 and string2 lines    
      $lookingFor = "string1";
    }    
  }   
}
```

**EDIT:** with regard to your edits, if you only need the `string2` line, remove `$string1Line` and its assignment, then return just `$_`. instead of `$string1Line + $_`.

Comment: This works! I'm going to do try it with the real file, but this far thank you!